# How to join ids of two columns into one field and replaces those ids by their names

Tags: sql, oracle

these are my tables.

```
Step

stepid     name
a           place1
b           place2          
c           place3
d           place4
e           place5
f           place6


Stage

stageid     start        finish
1            a            b
2            b            c
3            c            d
4            d            e
5            e            f

Trip

tripid     stageid       
1            1            
1            2            
1            3            
1            4      
1            5
```

I want to achieve this query result

```
tripid     stageid       
1          place1,place2,place3,place4,place5,place6
```

I know how put all ids into one field and how to replace ids by their assigned names. However I do not know how to join both of these solutions.

This is the sql I'm using for placing ids into one field.

```
SELECT REPLACE(stageid,'''') as stages
FROM (SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(stageid,' ') stageid, level 
FROM trip
START WITH stageid = (select min(stageid) from trip)
CONNECT BY PRIOR stageid < stageid
ORDER BY level DESC) 
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Start and finish are foreign keys of stepid and stageid of trip table is a foreign key of of stageid in Stage table
I work on oracle developer ver 3.2. Can you please help.

Comment: How does the data reach the output?  Seems to me like `tripid = 1` should only give `place1,place2` since `start=a` and `finish=b`

Comment: Well, for `tripid = 1` I get `1,2,3,4,5` and those numbers I want to replace with names from step table. The trip table is only partially presented in this case. In fact `tripid` is a foreigh key of some other table.

Comment: isn't start a reserved word you shouldnt be using as a column name?

Comment: It is a pure example, there is no need to show the actual database structure. I want it to be as easy as possible for "you" to understand and possibly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to `LISTAGG`, then this is one option which should be pretty close:

```
SELECT tripid, stages || ',' || step.name
FROM (
  SELECT trip.tripid, 
    LISTAGG(step.name, ',') within group (order by stage.stageid) stages,
    MAX(stage.stageId) maxStageId
  FROM stage
    INNER JOIN step on stage.startstep = step.stepid
    INNER JOIN trip on stage.stageid = trip.stageid
  GROUP BY trip.tripid
) t INNER JOIN stage ON t.maxStageId = stage.stageId
    INNER JOIN step on stage.finishstep = step.stepid
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25be3/2)

Basically it uses the startstep to build the list, and then concatonates the last finishstep based on the max stage id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, keep in mind I renamed `start` to `startid`:

```
SELECT tripid, REPLACE(stageid,'''') as stages
FROM (
    SELECT tripid, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(step.name,' ') stageid, level 
    FROM trip
    JOIN stage USING(stageid)
    JOIN step ON stage.startid=step.stepid
    START WITH stageid = (select min(stageid) from trip)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR stageid < stageid
    ORDER BY level DESC
  ) 
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

It just outputs the start step names instead of the ids, if you want to get all the places in the trip it would probably be easier by just joining start and end and using distinct

Here is a fiddle to play around with if anyone has a better idea:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d5d5/8

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do this is just to use `listagg()` to aggregate the strings.  Join the tables together and then aggregate them:

```
select t.tripid,
       listagg(st.name, ',') within group (order by st.stepid)
from trip t join
     stage s
     on t.stageid = s.stageid join
     step st
     on st.stepid in (s.start, s.finish)
group by t.tripid
```